# How to set the background color of Tab.Navigator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

As you can see below, I've tried many ways of setting the background color to green, all to no avail. The background remains blue like the image.

The `inactiveColor` and `activeColor` are working (white and red respectively).

[image: screenshot]

```
<NavigationContainer>

  <Tab.Navigator
    initialRouteName="HomeScreen"
    activeColor="red"
    inactiveColor="white"
    activeBackgroundColor="green"
    inactiveBackgroundColor="green"
    style={{ backgroundColor: 'green' }}
    tabBarOptions={{
      style:{
        backgroundColor: 'green'
      }
    }}
  >

    <Tab.Screen
      name="HomeScreen"
      options={{
        tabBarLabel: 'Home',
        tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
          <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={26} />
        ),
      }}
    >
    {props => <HomeScreen {...props} state={this.state} />}
    </Tab.Screen>

    <Tab.Screen
      name="Files"
      component={FilesScreen}
      options={{
        tabBarLabel: 'Files',
        tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
          <MaterialCommunityIcons name="file" color={color} size={26} />
        ),
      }}
    />

  </Tab.Navigator>

</NavigationContainer>
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
  "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.7",
  "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.1.7",
  "@react-navigation/native": "^5.1.4",
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Refer [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-bottom-tab-navigator#barstyle) here, You need to use barStyle.

Try

```
<Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Feed"
        shifting={true}
        labeled={false}
        sceneAnimationEnabled={false}
        activeColor="#00aea2"
        inactiveColor="#95a5a6"
        barStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#ffff' }}
```

Answer (score 29):

In React Navigation 6.x, you use `tabBarStyle`

```
<Tab.Navigator
  screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
    headerShown: false,
    tabBarStyle: {
      height: 90,
      paddingHorizontal: 5,
      paddingTop: 0,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(34,36,40,1)',
      position: 'absolute',
      borderTopWidth: 0,
  },
})}
  >
  <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
  <Tab.Screen name="List" component={RegistrationList} />
  <Tab.Screen name="News" component={News} />
  <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Comment: I tried your solution and everything is working except the tabBarStyle is only applied to 2 out of my 4 tabs why is that?

Comment: For some reason, background color for my first tab not changing, but other tabs design look okay. Any reason?

Comment: The tabBarStyle defined in Navigator is overwritten by tabBarStyle in Screen, hope this help somebody

Answer (score 15):

in the react-navigation V5 your can to do this:

```
 <Tab.Navigator
    initialRouteName={'Critic'}
    tabBarOptions={{
       activeTintColor: '#fff',
       inactiveTintColor: 'lightgray',
       activeBackgroundColor: '#c4461c',
       inactiveBackgroundColor: '#b55031',
           style: {
                 backgroundColor: '#CE4418',
                 paddingBottom: 3
           }
    }}
>
    <Tab.Screen name="Critic" component={Critic} options={CriticOptions} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Urgent" component={Urgent} options={UrgentOptions} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Moderate" component={Moderate} options={ModerateOptions} />
    <Tab.Screen name="All" component={All} options={AllOptions} />
 </Tab.Navigator>
);
```

Answer (score 12):

You need to add the backgroundColor in screenOptions. 
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#screenoptions
Try this:

```
<Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{
    tabBarOptions: {
        style: {
            backgroundColor: '#f9f9f9',
        },
    },
}}>
```

Answer (score 6):

you may try this

```
<Tab.Navigator 
screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        gestureEnabled: true,
        gestureDirection: 'horizontal',
        tabBarStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#3E48A0',
        },
      }}>
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

you can set the property in tabBarOptions of Tab.Navigator

```
 <Tab.Navigator
          screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
          ....
           })}

          tabBarOptions={{
            activeTintColor: 'tomato',
            inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
            showLabel: false,
            style: {backgroundColor: primaryLighterColor,},
          }}
    >
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    tabBarActiveTintColor: theme.colors.main,
    tabBarInactiveTintColor: theme.colors.text_detail,
    tabBarShowLabel: false,
    tabBarStyle: {
      paddingVertical: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 20 : 0,
      height: 78,
      backgroundColor: theme.colors.background_primary
    }
  }}
>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  <Tab.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
    tabBarActiveTintColor: "red",
    tabBarInactiveTintColor: "blue",
    tabBarStyle: {
      height: 55,
    },
    tabBarLabelStyle: {
      fontSize: 14,
      margin: 0,
    },
  }}>
```